# framer.motion animation is instant instead of animating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have several boxes that I want to animate through,

Here's a simple app example (Also a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-lehmann-je63y?file=/src/App.js))

Each "box" should fade in and fade out, however, in this example, the animation happens isntantly.

```
const Box = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
`;

const Test = ({ isActive }) => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      animate={isActive ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 3 }}
    >
      <Box>hello world</Box>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const boxes = [
    {
      component: ({ isActive }) => <Test isActive={isActive} />
    },
    {
      component: ({ isActive }) => <Test isActive={isActive} />
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div onClick={() => setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0)}>
        {boxes.map((box, index) => {
          const isActive = index === currentIndex;
          return <box.component isActive={isActive} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: in the codesandbox example, the animation is fading out. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question. Whenever the user clicks the parent div, the currentIndex switches and one of the boxes slowly fades out. What is your intended effect? The boxes do not 'fade in', is that what you would like to happen?

Comment: @TomBonynge yeah I would expect them to fade in AND fade out

Answer (score 2):

I have never used framer.motion before, but looking at their documentation, I think you can use variants, to achieve what you need. https://www.framer.com/api/motion/examples/

I've slightly refactored your code, to get it working:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Box = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
`;

const variants = {
  open: { opacity: 1 },
  closed: { opacity: 0 }
};

const Test = ({ index, currentIndex }) => {
  return (
    <motion.div
      animate={index === currentIndex ? "open" : "closed"}
      variants={variants}
      transition={{ duration: 3 }}
    >
      <Box>hello world</Box>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const boxes = ["a", "b"];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{currentIndex}</h2>
      <div onClick={() => setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0)}>
        {boxes.map((box, i) => {
          return <Test index={i} currentIndex={currentIndex} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the currentIndex is passed as props to the child Test components, they check themselves whether their index matches the currentIndex and update their animations accordingly.

Edited codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-austin-tymvx

Comment: Ah thanks for your input Tom, it was actually an issue with delcaring the array of components inside the function, once I delcared the array outside of the component they wouldn't re-render on every state update, see here https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-mendel-b36jw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: To take this even further, I needed to pass in the components certain props from the parent, so I needed them in the body of the functional component. But to avoid re-rendering, I wrapped the boxes in `useMemo`.

Answer (score 1):

In framer motion, you have [useCycle](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/utilities/#usecycle) properties. Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-cycle-forked-j861y?file=/src/index.tsx).

Code in example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Frame, useCycle } from "framer";
import "./styles.css";

export function MyComponent() {
  const [animate, cycle] = useCycle(
    { scale: 1.5, rotate: 0, opacity: 1 },
    { scale: 1.0, rotate: 90, opacity: 0 }
  );
  return (
    <Frame
      animate={animate}
      onTap={() => cycle()}
      size={150}
      radius={30}
      background={"#fff"}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<MyComponent />, rootElement);
```

and some simple css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 85, 255, 1);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
```

I don't recommend you to use this type of construction:  `animate={index === currentIndex ? "open" : "closed"}` , because you might have some lagging/breaking animation.
Try always to search examples/elements of MotionAPI lib. You will have less code lines and mostly "clean" code with no useless variables.